# Mongoose Web Server Can't load php file

Tags: javascript, php, mongoose, web-development-server

I have the following JS:

```
//Testing AJAX / php here
function testPHP(){
if (false) { 
    return;
} else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "test.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

testPHP();
```

And the test.php:

```
<?php
    echo "You called me from server";
>
```

Whenever I try to run this, I get '500 Internal server error'.
I'm running Mongoose web server. Is there a way to fix this, or at least tell in further detail what's going wrong?

So I went into the web server hexDump, and I found this.
   HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server error.. Content-Length:138..Content - Type" text/plain....500 Internal Server Error.CGI program sent malformed headers: [HTTP/1.1 200 OK...

Comment: close php with ?> instead of >